# Probability of at least 1 person in Group A being in a group of X size with a general population

Tags: probability

im trying to find a mathematical way to calculate the percentage chance that there is at least 1 Cheater in any given match chosen at random.

Game has 100 players per match

Total Players (including the Cheaters): 3000

there are 3 scenarios needing to be tested, a group of 500, 100, 25 Cheaters

i need to calculate the chance that there is at least 1 cheater in any random match, if someone could supply at least a formula and an example this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following notation.

Population of Players: $P$

Number of Cheaters: $C$

Number of players in a match: $M$

The probability of at least one cheater in a match is $1$ minus the probability that there are no cheaters in the match.

$$1-\dfrac{\dbinom{P-C}{M}}{\dbinom{P}{M}}$$

In the scenarios you chose:

$$P=3000, M=100, C=500: \\ \\ 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{2500}{100}}{\dbinom{3000}{100}} \approx 100\%$$

$$P=3000, M=100, C=100: \\ \\ 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{2900}{100}}{\dbinom{3000}{100}} \approx 96.82\%$$

$$P=3000, M=100, C=25: \\ \\ 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{2975}{100}}{\dbinom{3000}{100}} \approx 57.3\%$$